# Value extraction in nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list like this:

```
mylist = Range[5*#, 5 # + 4] & /@ Range[1, 5]
```

> {{5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, {15, 16, 17, 18, 19}, {20, 21,
>   22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27, 28, 29}}

Simple question: how can I extract the multiple elements of this list?

For example:

`mylist[[1,3]]` gives

> 7

`mylist[[{1,3}]]` gives

> {{5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {15, 16, 17, 18, 19}}

But how do I get for example the 3rd element of the first sublist **and** the 4th element of the fifth sublist? Something like {{7},{28}}?

I tried something like this:

```
mylist[[{{1, 3}, {5, 4}}]]
```

or

```
mylist[[{1, 3}, {5, 4}]]
```

But that didn't work...

Bonusquestion: why did that last code give the following result instead?

> {{9, 8}, {19, 18}}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `Extract`

```
Extract[mylist, {{1, 3}, {5, 4}}]
```

> `{7, 28}`

What

```
mylist[[{1, 3}, {5, 4}]]
```

does is that it takes the first and third sublist, and then takes the fifth and fourth element from each of those lists.

Comment: Is there no shorthand for Extract?

Comment: @ImreVégh No, there isn't. You could say that `Extract` is a shorthand for what kglr posted, though.

Answer (score 3):

```
mylist[[##]] & @@@ {{1, 3}, {5, 4}}
```

> {7, 28}